# Typing code into a SO box?

Tags: discussion

My question that I want to present on SO, includes the literal text that Git inserted into my files. But if I cut-and-paste that into this SO question box, it gets some pretty crazy formatting!  What is the actual procedure for doing this? Are there special symbols to insert, that indicate 'do not format this section' ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the help? [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Looked for that - didn't find it. But thanks.

Comment: A simple google search with the terms "stackoverflow" and "format" or "formatting" would have given you this article as the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put four spaces in front of every line

```
Preformatted text here.
```

Or using > to make a blockquote.

> Blockquote here.